# Socket_read() says "not a valid resource"

Tags: php, sockets

I am learning socket programming and experimenting using php.
I wanted to connect to a socket-server using a client and read the response of the server from the client.

Codes for :

### Server.php:

```
$address="127.0.0.1";
$port=3343;
echo "I am here";
set_time_limit (0);
if(false==($socket=  socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)))
{
    echo "could not create socket";
}
socket_bind($socket, $address, $port) or die ("could not bind socket");
socket_listen($socket);
if(($client=socket_accept($socket)))
    socket_write($client, "Welcome!!", 1024);

socket_close($socket);
```

### Client.php

```
$host="127.0.0.1" ;
$port=3343;
$timeout=30;
$sk=fsockopen($host,$port,$errnum,$errstr,$timeout) ;
if (!is_resource($sk)) {
    exit("connection fail: ".$errnum." ".$errstr) ;
} else {
    echo socket_read($sk, 256);
    //echo "Connected";
}
```

On connecting,

Server output :

```
I am here
```

Client Output :

```
Warning: socket_read(): supplied resource is not a valid Socket resource in C:\xampp\htdocs\users\srv\test\client.php on line 16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem here.

socket_read() doesn't work with sockets which have not been created with socket_create().

Working code :

```
$host="127.0.0.1" ;
$port=3343;
$timeout=30;
$sk=fsockopen($host,$port,$errnum,$errstr,$timeout) ;
if (!is_resource($sk)) {
    exit("connection fail: ".$errnum." ".$errstr) ;
} else {
    while (!feof($sk)) echo fgets($sk, 256); //This does the trick
    //echo "Connected";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing the resource types.

`fsockopen` returns a file pointer. You need to use `fread`, `fwrite` etc. on it, and not `socket_read`.

`socket_read` accepts socket resources create with `socket_create` or `socket_accept`

Example for `fsockopen` from the PHP manual page:

```
<?php
$fp = fsockopen("udp://127.0.0.1", 13, $errno, $errstr);
if (!$fp) {
    echo "ERROR: $errno - $errstr<br />\n";
} else {
    fwrite($fp, "\n");
    echo fread($fp, 26);
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

[fsockopen reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fsockopen.php)

[socket_read reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-read.php)