# socket_select() not a valid socket

Tags: php, sockets

I got this error:

> Warning: socket_select(): supplied argument is not a valid Socket resource in /volume1/web/is/xxxx/listen-new.php on line 12
>   PHP Warning:  socket_select(): supplied argument is not a valid Socket resource in /volume1/web/is/xxxx/listen-new.php on line 12
>   this my snippet code

My code is:

```
    $port = $this->port;
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
    socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
    socket_bind($sock, 0, $port);
    socket_listen($sock);
    $this->clients[] = $sock;
    $data = array();        
    while (true) {
        $read = $this->clients;
        $write = array(); //NULL
        $except = array();//NULL
        $sckt = socket_select($read, $write, $except, 0);
        if($sckt === false){
             echo "socket_select() failed, reason: " .
                    socket_strerror(socket_last_error()) . "\n";
        }
        elseif($sckt > 0) {
            if (in_array($sock, $read)) {
                $this->clients[] = $newsock = socket_accept($sock);
                //var_dump($this->gps);
                socket_write($newsock, "Connected\n");
                //var_dump($this->gps);
                /**try{
                    socket_getpeername($newsock, $ip); //error
                    echo "New client connected: {$ip}\n";              
                }
                catch(Exception $e){
                    echo "error : $e->getMessage()\n";
                }**/
                $key = array_search($sock, $read);
                unset($read[$key]);
            }           
            foreach ($read as $read_sock) {
                $data = @socket_read($read_sock, 2048);             
                if ($data === false) {
                    $gpsdisc = array_search($read_sock, array_column($this->gps, 'pid'));
                    $key = array_search($read_sock, $this->clients);
                    unset($this->clients[$key]);
                    unset($this->gps[$gpsdisc]);
                    echo "client disconnected.\n";


                    continue;
                }
                else{
                    $data = trim($data);
                    if (!empty($data)) {
                        var_dump($data);
                        $buf = bin2hex($data);
                        $start = substr($buf, 0,4);     
                        if($start=="7878"){
                            $protocol = substr($buf, 6,2);                          
                            if($protocol=="01"){
                                $imei = substr($buf, 8,16);
                                $cariGPS = $this->cariGPS($imei);
                                if($cariGPS!=NULL){
                                    $this->setGPS($imei,$read_sock,$cariGPS);
                                    $reply = $this->authLogin($data);
                                    $rep = hex2bin("$reply");
                                    socket_write($read_sock, $rep, strlen($rep));
                                }
                                else
                                    echo "$imei salah";
                            }
                            elseif($protocol=="15"){
                                //echo "$buf\n";
                                $this->reply($data);
                            }
                            elseif($protocol=="12"){
                                $hex12 = bin2hex($data);
                                //echo "$hex12\n";
                            }
                            else{
                                $hex12 = bin2hex($data);                            
                                echo "$hex12\n";
                            }

                            echo "$protocol\n";
                        }
                        else{
                            if($data=="where"){
                                //echo $data."\n";
                                $this->where($this->gps);                                   
                            }
                            elseif($data=="quit"){
                                $gpsdisc = array_search($read_sock, array_column($this->gps, 'pid'));
                                unset($this->gps[$gpsdisc]);
                                socket_close($read_sock);
                                $key = array_search($read_sock, $this->clients);
                                unset($this->clients[$key]);
                            }
                            else{
                                echo "command not found\n";
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }              
            }
        }
    }
    socket_close($sock);
```

**PS** I also had to change `$write = null` and `$except = null`

Are there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you supplied only the server code but omitted the client code. Can you post the client code please? I guess the problem is there. With my test client (fyi I used socket_create) I cannot reproduce the problem you are reporting. 
Also mine is php7 (if you are curious).
This may have some hints for you: [Socket_read() says "not a valid resource"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060616/socket-read-says-not-a-valid-resource)

Comment: Hey, Your version of client is working ok on my system - at least I am NOT getting the "not a valid socket resource" msg. Please note - I got rid of/simplified the class variables while testing as the complete class definition is not in your first post. Can you post the complete first file, how you are running the clients and the server as well as some details about your test environment please? Thanks.

Comment: i deploy with php7 and my server is php5
"Hey, Your version of client is working ok on my system"
yes me too,but after some hours my server code show error not a valid Socket resource
PS : i use this for GPS listener transmission

Comment: Any luck with this @akbar ? It seems like PHP7 is causing this b/c the same thing happens to me in PHP7 with code that worked fine in 5.5

Comment: My issue was resolved because previously the code looked like `$this->sockets = array(&$this->sock)`. Removing the pass by reference `&` fixed it in PHP7.