# PHP Sockets and Whatsapp Proxy

Tags: php, sockets, whatsapp

I'm building a small project regarding WhatsApp, and I'm using the https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API, even though there's no longer support on the repo.

My issue is with sockets, and I'm using them to log in. The section of my code which is failing is :

```
<?php
$socket = fsockopen("e" . rand(1, 16) . ".whatsapp.net:" . Constants::PORT);
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array(
    'sec' => Constants::TIMEOUT_SEC,
    'usec' => Constants::TIMEOUT_USEC
));

socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array(
    'sec' => Constants::TIMEOUT_SEC,
    'usec' => Constants::TIMEOUT_USEC
));

?>
```

I'm getting the following  error:

> C:\MAMP\htdocs\WhatsappTestApp\whatsapp\src\whatsprot.class.php on line 305
>
> [10-May-2017 15:11:13 Africa/Johannesburg] PHP Warning:  socket_set_option(): supplied resource is not a valid Socket resource in C:\MAMP\htdocs\WhatsappTestApp\whatsapp\src\whatsprot.class.php on line 291
>
> [10-May-2017 15:11:13 Africa/Johannesburg] PHP Warning:  socket_set_option(): supplied resource is not a valid Socket resource in C:\MAMP\htdocs\WhatsappTestApp\whatsapp\src\whatsprot.class.php on line 296
>
> [10-May-2017 15:11:13 Africa/Johannesburg] PHP Warning:  socket_read(): supplied resource is not a valid Socket resource in C:\MAMP\htdocs\WhatsappTestApp\whatsapp\src\whatsprot.class.php on line 299
>
> [10-May-2017 15:11:13 Africa/Johannesburg] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught FailedProxy: [0]: Failed proxy. Error 3
>
> thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\WhatsappTestApp\whatsapp\src\whatsprot.class.php on line 301

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Socket\_read() says "not a valid resource"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29060616/socket-read-says-not-a-valid-resource)

Comment: No, I don't think so, I've seen that one, Their doing sockets to the localhost where as I'm using sockets for Whatsapp server

Comment: That's irrelevant, you're still mixing resources

Comment: @t.m.adam I checked that one. And I do have a socket_read there after:

     $socket_result = trim(socket_read($socket, 8192));

Comment: That is also a problem . Try creating the `$socket` with `socket_create`

Comment: I will post an example with `fsockopen`

Comment: @GregSithole I am also trying to work with that API, can you give some information that how did you extracted the whatsapp password??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you're mixing files with sockets , so PHP throws an error .  To fix this, you can either create a socket with `socket_create`, or use `stream_set_timeout` to set the timeout and use filesystem functions to read / write to the socket :

```
<?php
$protocol = "tcp";    /* or "ssl" for HTTPS */
$host = "e" . rand(1, 16) . ".whatsapp.net";
$fp = fsockopen("$protocol://$host", Constants::PORT, $errn, $errm);
stream_set_timeout($fp, Constants::TIMEOUT_SEC);

/* You can treat $fp the same way you would treat a file */
//$data = fread($fp, 8192); 
//fwrite($fp, "my data");   
//fclose($fp);
?>
```

If you want to use sockets then `$socket` should be a socket resource :

```
<?php 
$host = "e" . rand(1, 16) . ".whatsapp.net";
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($socket, $host, Constants::PORT);

socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, array(
    'sec' => Constants::TIMEOUT_SEC,
    'usec' => Constants::TIMEOUT_USEC
));
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_SNDTIMEO, array(
    'sec' => Constants::TIMEOUT_SEC,
    'usec' => Constants::TIMEOUT_USEC
));
?>
```

Comment: I kinda tried your method differently, but I'm getting a 400 Bad Request. I just changed how I was using the socket connection... but that's what I got.

Comment: Also tried that other guy one... but still got the same error.

Comment: The 400 error means that you propably send some bad headers , can you include the `$data` you send to the `$host` . Also if the `$host` uses ssl , you should use the first example i posted .

Comment: I'm not sure whether the host does use the SSL, but I stopped getting a 400 Bad Request when I used your second code with the socket as a resource because I need it as a resource. So after implemetning what you did over there: I now get a 

"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.'

Comment: What port are trying to connect ? I can't connect to port 80 on any .whatsapp.net  in range e1 - e16 .

Comment: Port 443 is used for HTTPS ( ssl ) . You need to use to use the first example i posted , but change : `$protocol = "tcp";` to : `$protocol = "ssl";`

Comment: I tried using the 1st example but when I tried to var_dump the fread, it returns a blank.

Comment: Yes , i'm getting an empty response too . There may be an issue with the HTTP headers . Can you include in your post the data you send to the `$host` ?

Comment: I can't open it with a web browser either . This propably has something to do with the whatsapp server . In that case there is not much you can do

Comment: To be honest with you, I'm not sending any data, I just trying to create a socket to Whatsapp Network.

Comment: Yep, I agree with you man, but thanks for your help though, and I'll accept your Answer.

Comment: If you don't send a request , you won't get a response . Still the connection is made , you can check it if you print `$errno` ( it should print `0` if connected successfully ) . I can't figure out why it won't respond to a web server though .

Comment: Checked that as well... It returns a 0... but I don't feel that's a success message because I'm supposed to receive a Success Message

Comment: I tried sending some basic HTTP headers ( User-Agent , Referer,  etc ) , but i can't get a response , and i can't connect with a browser either . That means that either there is a problem with the server or that it expects some 'special' headers . I 'll see if i can find some info on google , if i do i 'll let you know

Comment: I couldn't read the full code as it is literally thousandas of lines over many files . It turns out that the app uses [libaxolotl](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/tree/master/src/libaxolotl-php) for encryption , not ssl and handles connections with sockets , not streams . I recommend you try with a clean installation of [Chat-API](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/tree/master/src) , see how it works , and if you need to modify it do it in small steps and allways keep backups

Comment: That's the one I was using and I've modified it to have e1.whatsapp.net server to allow me to connect. The owner of the repo, announced an End of Support last year, so I got the repo, but there's not much I can do with it.

Comment: Then it could be a broblem with the server since the developer stop maintaining it . If you insist on using the app , i suggest you try with a clean installation . If it still doesn't work , there's nothing more you can do ..

Comment: Whatsapp Server? Yep, I pretty much guessed. I'll figure this one out, thanks man